# How could I add a border to make element look like a tree and keep it positioned correctly when resizing?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to step away from [jsTree](https://www.jstree.com/) as this is not as much as configurable as having my own custom code. I am making use of [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/) to have a somewhat similar functionality as jsTree. I am also stepping away from [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) (for now), because of debugging reasons.

```js
//Event delegation
function BindEvent(parent, eventType, ele, func) {
  var element = document.querySelector(parent);

  element.addEventListener(eventType, function(event) {
    var possibleTargets = element.querySelectorAll(ele);
    var target = event.target;

    for (var i = 0, l = possibleTargets.length; i < l; i++) {
      var el = target;
      var p = possibleTargets[i];

      while (el && el !== element) {
        if (el === p) {
          return func.call(p, event);
        }

        el = el.parentNode;
      }
    }
  });
}

//Add content after referenced element
function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
  referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

//Custom function
function LoadSubOptions(ele) {
  ele = ele.parentElement.parentElement;
  let newEle = document.createElement("div");
  newEle.classList.add("row", "flex");
  //Generated HTML Content (currently hard coded):
  newEle.innerHTML = "<div class='col-xs-1'><div class='tree-border'></div></div><div class='col-xs-11'><div class='row'><div class='col-xs-12'><button class='btn btn-default btn-block btn-lg'>Test</button></div></div></div>";
  insertAfter(ele, newEle);
}

//Bind method(s) on button click(s)
BindEvent("#tree-replacement", "click", "button", function(e) {
  LoadSubOptions(this);
});
```

```css
#tree-replacement button {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.tree-border {
  border-left: 1px dashed #000;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}


/*Probably not wise to use this method on Bootstrap's grid system: */

#tree-replacement .row.flex>[class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div id="tree-replacement">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-lg">
          Option 1
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-lg">
          Option 2
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--The generated html as example: -->
    <!--<div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <div class="tree-border">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-11">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-lg">
              Option 2
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>-->
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3vt8uqf9/1/)

I added a border in a `.column-*-1` to allow for some spacing for the border:

[image: Border gap to button]

The spacing however, I find a bit too much. How could I address this problem? I would like to refrain from styling Bootstrap's grid system (meaning I preferably would not want to touch any styling behind `.col-*` and `.row` classes etc.) because this might break the responsiveness or anything else related to Bootstrap.

**Edit:**
I also noticed that when adding a lot of buttons by just clicking them, the layout of tree will start failing as well. (I am aware this is a different question, so if I need to post another question regarding this problem, please do let me know) Is there a way I could address this so that the element works correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Here I have used `absolute` positioning and increased height by `5px` which kind of makes it touches the next div element.

Here is the [Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/25sy8pt0/)

and the Code Snippet:

```js
//Event delegation
function BindEvent(parent, eventType, ele, func) {
  var element = document.querySelector(parent);

  element.addEventListener(eventType, function(event) {
    var possibleTargets = element.querySelectorAll(ele);
    var target = event.target;

    for (var i = 0, l = possibleTargets.length; i < l; i++) {
      var el = target;
      var p = possibleTargets[i];

      while (el && el !== element) {
        if (el === p) {
          return func.call(p, event);
        }

        el = el.parentNode;
      }
    }
  });
}

//Add content after referenced element
function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
  referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

//Custom function
function LoadSubOptions(ele) {
  ele = ele.parentElement.parentElement;
  let newEle = document.createElement("div");
  newEle.classList.add("row", "flex");
  //Generated HTML Content (currently hard coded):
  newEle.innerHTML = "<div class='col-xs-1'><div class='tree-border'></div></div><div class='col-xs-11'><div class='row'><div class='col-xs-12'><button class='btn btn-default btn-block btn-lg'>Test</button></div></div></div>";
  insertAfter(ele, newEle);
}

//Bind method(s) on button click(s)
BindEvent("#tree-replacement", "click", "button", function(e) {
  LoadSubOptions(this);
});
```

```css
#tree-replacement button {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.tree-border {
  border-left: 1px dashed #000;
  height: calc(100% + 5px);
  margin-left: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}

.flex {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.col-xs-11 .col-xs-12 {
    padding-left: 0;
}

/*Probably not wise to use this method on Bootstrap's grid system: */

#tree-replacement .row.flex>[class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div id="tree-replacement">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-lg">
          Option 1
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-lg">
          Option 2
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--<div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <div class="tree-border">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-11">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-lg">
              Option 2
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was talking about the space between the bord and the button right of it, but this was also a problem which I needed to address.

Comment: what exactly?? I don't understand !!

Comment: Like so: https://i.imgur.com/kNTjAwv.png , I would like to decrease that spacing.

Comment: Yes exactly Joykal

Comment: I have updated the code by removing the padding-left of child elements

Comment: How come the borders are positioned differently on the children? This is unwanted behaviour: https://i.imgur.com/Fu0Qr42.png , opening enough buttons will cause the following: https://i.imgur.com/EPuNnEA.png

Answer (score 1):

Add this little CSS

```
#tree-replacement .row.flex > .col-xs-11:nth-child(2):before {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(-100% / 11 + 30px);
    top: 2em;
    border-top: 1px dashed #000000;
    width: calc(100% / 5 - 15px);
}
```

```js
//Event delegation
function BindEvent(parent, eventType, ele, func) {
  var element = document.querySelector(parent);

  element.addEventListener(eventType, function(event) {
    var possibleTargets = element.querySelectorAll(ele);
    var target = event.target;

    for (var i = 0, l = possibleTargets.length; i < l; i++) {
      var el = target;
      var p = possibleTargets[i];

      while (el && el !== element) {
        if (el === p) {
          return func.call(p, event);
        }

        el = el.parentNode;
      }
    }
  });
}

//Add content after referenced element
function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
  referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

//Custom function
function LoadSubOptions(ele) {
  ele = ele.parentElement.parentElement;
  let newEle = document.createElement("div");
  newEle.classList.add("row", "flex");
  //Generated HTML Content (currently hard coded):
  newEle.innerHTML = "<div class='col-xs-1'><div class='tree-border'></div></div><div class='col-xs-11'><div class='row'><div class='col-xs-12'><button class='btn btn-default btn-block btn-lg'>Test</button></div></div></div>";
  insertAfter(ele, newEle);
}

//Bind method(s) on button click(s)
BindEvent("#tree-replacement", "click", "button", function(e) {
  LoadSubOptions(this);
});
```

```css
#tree-replacement button {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.tree-border {
  border-left: 1px dashed #000;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}


/*Probably not wise to use this method on Bootstrap's grid system: */

#tree-replacement .row.flex>[class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#tree-replacement .row.flex > .col-xs-11:nth-child(2):before {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(-100% / 11 + 30px);
    top: 2em;
    border-top: 1px dashed #000000;
    width: calc(100% / 5 - 15px);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div id="tree-replacement">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-lg">
          Option 1
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-lg">
          Option 2
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--The generated html as example: -->
    <!--<div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <div class="tree-border">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-11">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-lg">
              Option 2
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is some neat stuff, not really answering my question but very useful.